# The duality problem of the optimal problem of 2 norm and 1 norm is included in the constraint

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

\begin{align*}
           \delta_r^*({\nu}) &= \max_{{\beta \in R^M}}\bigg\{{\beta}'{\nu}\mid
           \frac{1}{P}\|{z}-{Y}{\beta}\|_2^2+\lambda\|{\beta}\|_1\leq\hat{\rho}+r\bigg\} \\
           &= \max_{{\beta\in R^M},g\geq0,\,h\geq0}\bigg\{{\beta}'{\nu}\mid
           \|{z}-{Y}{\beta}\|_2^2\leq g,\,\|{\beta}\|_1\leq h,\,
           \frac{1}{P}g+\lambda h\leq\hat{\rho}+r\bigg\}.
           \end{align*}
It follows from strong duality that
$$
      \begin{array}{rll}
      \delta_r^*({\nu}) = \min         &   (\hat{\rho}+r) s + {u-v}+{z}' \\
  \mathrm{s.t.} &    {Y}' {w} - {t} = {\nu},  \\
                                                         &  \bigg \|  \begin{array}{c} 2v\\ {w}    \end{array} \bigg \|_2 \leq 2u, \\
                                                         & \| {t}  \|_\infty \leq  \lambda s, \\
                                                         & Pu + Pv \leq s ,\\
                                                         & u,s \in \mathbb{R}_+,\,v\in \mathbb{R},\,{w}\in \mathbb{R}^P,\,{t}\in \mathbb{R}^M.                      
       \end{array}          $$

How is the dual of this optimization problem solved

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no question here, and it is hard to follow how you obtained the dual.

Comment: Zhu, Taozeng, Jingui Xie, and Melvyn Sim. "Joint estimation and robustness optimization." Management Science 68.3 (2022): 1659-1677.
The above derivation comes from this paper and I am not clear how it is derived.